# Fade in hidden div with CSS transition

Tags: html, css

I have an image positioned within a `div`. When you hover over the div, it displays a caption over the top. The caption `div` has a background colour that I'd like to fade in. Is this possible? I've tried applying a transition, but it doesn't seem to work for block elements.

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bojcL0vb/3/) and code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="box">
    <img src="http://bit.ly/1G1Pcbz" alt="coding">
    <div class="overlay">
        This is my caption overlay.
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
  height: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 117px;
    background: #ccc;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
.overlay {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: red;
    z-index: 9999;
}
.box:hover .overlay {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Move the `transition` property from `.box` to `.overlay`, and animate opacity *instead of* display:

```
.overlay {
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
  opacity: 0;
}

.box:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/g5zd3ca7/)

Comment: Good answer, but opacity values range between 0 and 1, (not 100)

Comment: Duh, I was thinking in percentages.  Updated, thanks!

Answer (score -2):

I have found the jQuery function .fadeIn() to be easy to use.  Documentation can be found here:

http://api.jquery.com/fadein/